# CMake, Visual Studio and include_external_msproject. Change project settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt that produces a .SLN file with 3 projects (libraries) generated on-the-fly and 1 C# - project included by include_external_msproject. So one of the project is created manually and its settings are constant.

Can i affect the settings of that project from CMakeLists.txt somehow? The environment variables are not good, because .SLN might be generated in one environment (some console window), but VS launched with that .SLN from another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any special infrastructure in CMake for handling .sln files. The include_external_msproject()` command only creates a CMake target, which references your project.

So, only thing you can try - rewrite your .sln file manually with `file(READ ...)` and `file(WRITE ...)` or, maybe, `configure_file()`.